# PHP - JSON to Array, iterate and print to string

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I receive below JSON object in a HTTP request:

```
{
"name": "myjsonstring",
"statisticalvalues": [
  {
    "key_0":"677876"
  },
  {
    "key_0":"0"
  },
],
"commoditycodes": [
  {
    "key_0":"90001000"
  },
  {
    "key_0":"80001000"
  },
]
}
```

I want to get the above values like `statisticalvalues & commoditycodes`, like:

```
JSON Information:
677876      90001000
0           80001000
```

My initial thought was to add this to an array:

```
    $returnArray = [];

    //Input
    foreach ($request->input() as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'commoditycodes') {
            $returnArray['commoditycodes'][] = $value;
        }
        if ($key === 'statisticalvalues') {
            $returnArray['statisticalvalues'][] = $value;
        }
    }
```

I then want to output it like above, but I am not sure how to iterate it like: `statisticalvalues |  commoditycodes`

```
    //Output:
    foreach ($returnArray as $value) {
        print_r($value);
        die();
    }
```

Am I on the right track? Can anyone help me with generating the correct output format?

Comment: I'd suggest the usage of the php json decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: ☝️ Guys, does it sound at all like decoding the JSON is the issue?!

Comment: The issue is not converting the JSON object to an array, but rather getting the correct output.

Comment: @oliverbj is PHP a hard requirement? Are you open to a one line [jq command line filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to transform your JSON data to the expected text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `json_decode()` to decode the JSON first. Then loop through its `statisticalvalues`, find the corresponding `commoditycodes` with the same array index in the `commoditycodes` array. Keep in mind that the actual values are under a property named `key_0`.

```
<?php
$json = '{"name":"myjsonstring","statisticalvalues":[{"key_0":"677876"},{"key_0":"0"}],"commoditycodes":[{"key_0":"90001000"},{"key_0":"80001000"}]}';
$obj = json_decode($json,false);
foreach ($obj->statisticalvalues as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->key_0 . "\t\t" . $obj->commoditycodes[$key]->key_0 . "\n";
}
?>
```

In your case, might be:

```
<?php
$obj = $request->input();
foreach ($obj["statisticalvalues"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["key_0"] . "\t\t" . $obj["commoditycodes"][$key]["key_0"] . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Ricky! I am not able to use this dynamically. I have this as my $json: 
`$json = $request->json();` - but this gives me this error: `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`

Comment: I think your `$request->json();` is already an object or an array as you mentioned. You can just skip the decode part. If it is an array, replace `->statisticalvalues` with `['statisticalvalues']` and `->key_0` with `['key_0']`.